# git push heroku master: error

Tags: php, git, heroku

I'm uploading a php project on Heroku and I'm following the instructions given on official website. When I reach the last command

`git push heroku master`

I receive the following error:

```
error: protocol https not supported or disabled in libcurl while accessing https://git.heroku.com/hidden-hamlet-3511.git/info/refs?service=git-receive-pack 
fatal: HTTP request failed.
```

I've searched around and couldn't find any solution.

Answer (score 0):

Heroku deploys are managed via [git](http://git-scm.org). Git has a concept called *remote repositories*; that is, repositories stored on another machine. When you `git push`, you're sending data to one of these remote repositories. `git push heroku master` means "push to the `master` branch on the remote repository named `heroku`."

You can use the `git remote` command to view the configured remotes for your repository. For instance, if you run `git remote -v`, you'll probably see something like this (you might have others listed too).

```
user@host dir$ git remote -v
heroku      https://git.heroku.com/hidden-hamlet-3511.git (push)
heroku      https://git.heroku.com/hidden-hamlet-3511.git (fetch)
```

Git can work with remotes via two protocols: **http** and **ssh**. Your remote is set up to use http (the default for Heroku), but your `libcurl` library doesn't have support for SSL, which is used for https. That's what your error message means - git can't use https to access its remote.

If you've [set up SSH keys for your Heroku account](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/keys) you can remove the https remote, and reconfigure it as an ssh remote:

```
git remote rm heroku
git remote add heroku git@heroku.com:hidden-hamlet-3511.git
```

You can also use the `heroku` command to add an ssh remote for you, after removing the old one:

```
git remote rm heroku
heroku git:remote -a hidden-hamlet-3511 --ssh-git
```

The Heroku documentation has [more information about using SSH with git remotes](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git#ssh-git-transport).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I found somewhere to add two files `composer.json` and `composer.lock` in root folder and the project would upload. And this works in my case. Add this suggestion into your question if you think it can be a reason and I'd accept your answer.